# Visualforce Page Timing Out in Lightning but OK in Classic

Tags: lightning

I have over-ridden the standard Edit button. The button loads a VF Page that displays **11 child records**. The page is timing out in Lightning mode but does not when in Classic. However, if the VF page has **10 records** it loads OK in Lightning.

Any idea why a VF page might time out in Lightning but not in Classic?

Chrome inspector is revealing 500 Server Error. Here is the specific error message shown:

> [LEXI:navigator:communication] failed to connect with lightning
>   experience WindowMessengerTimeoutError: Timeout exceeded waiting for
>   handshake to complete from parent at new b

Comment: Do you like to share a sample code which causes the issue please? also [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_view_system_log.htm&type=5) could help find where it is slowing down. Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the sample code. I was wondering if the **error message** is ringing any bells?

Comment: May be you can do a sample code to simulate, and share that. I would usually do it to prove my concept.. and sometimes you would find the issue while replicating the same thing in simple manner. cheers!